# li:first-child for specific class in list?

Tags: jquery, css

i have a list, which is like this:

```
<ul>
  <li class="empty">bla</li>
  <li class="item">text1</li>
  <li class="item">text2</li>
<ul>
```

Is it now possible to select e.g via JQuery the `li:first-child` of a specific class?

I don't want to select the `class="empty"`, i want to select the first item of "item"...

`$('ul li.item:first-child')` is not working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('ul li.item:first');
```

or

```
$('ul li.item').first();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZMsdd/1/

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `:first-child` because it's defined as: *"Selects all elements that are the first child of their parent."* and that is not true in your case. However, `:first` is defined as: *"Selects the first matched element."*. And that works:

```
$('ul li.item:first')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n4JhH/

However, it actually does not work probably if there are multiple `ul` you want to apply this one. Then you have to apply it for each with `$('ul').each(...)` <- I don't know whether there is an easier solution.

Comment: Hey, thanks.  solved it with `$("li.search_list_item", '.search_list').first()` ;-)

Comment: @Torben Okay, cool :) Notice that `$('foo:first')` is the same as `$('foo').first()`.

Comment: ...and therefore the same problem exists if you have multiple `ul`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can be used

```
$("li.item").first().hide();
```

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/uPjP9/

Answer (score -1):

[edited] This should work

`$('ul li:not(.empty):first')`

http://jsfiddle.net/H9rxx/

Comment: -1 I downvoted this because the question says 'the first li with a class of item'. The code here takes the first item from the list if it doesn't have a class of empty.

Comment: Fair enough! There are other solutions stated to the specific problem.